# entering different date time formats

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm reading from an oracle database a date in this format: dd/mm/yyyy HH24:mi:ss.
when i write a query i have to write the whole date with seconds and minutes.
i need a way to write a query without giving this HH24:mi:ss.
how can i enter a date like 4/7/2011 and get it in this format dd/mm/yyyy HH24:mi:ss
this is the query:

```
q = "select * from MPOS t where t.TRANSACID='" + n +
                "'and t.REPORTDATE between to_date('" + st + "', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:mi:ss')"
                + " and to_date('" + end + "', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:mi:ss')";
```

where st and end are DateTime

Answer (score 0):

try use ToShortDateString():

```
q = "select * from MPOS t where t.TRANSACID='" + n +
    "'and t.REPORTDATE between to_date('" + st.ToShortDateString() + "', 'dd/mm/yyyy')" +
    " and to_date('" + end.ToShortDateString() + "', 'dd/mm/yyyy')";
```

I think you will also have to change the order of dd and mm so it would be 'mm/dd/yyyy'

Comment: i can't alter the database. i need to change the datetime format in my c# program

Comment: @ZeinaAbd it doesn't alter your table, it just represent the input as datetime oracle will know, it's ok, try this.

Comment: it didn't work. how can i change st?? like add the time manually?